# Writing a Simple Subscriber

Tags: ros, callback, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went through the ROS tutorial for writing a simple publisher and subscriber with the '/chatter' topic, and I'm able to successfully subscribe to the 'chatter' topic and respond with the chatterCallback.

I wish to implement this simple subscriber with another existing ROS topic, called '/points', which is a PointCloud2 message. This topic shows up when I type 'rostopic list' and 'rostopic echo /points'. However, the subscriber will not respond when I change the topic from '/chatter' to '/points'.

I already modified the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml file to add the 'sensor_msgs' package as a build and run dependency. Is there something else I need to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225016/writing-a-simple-subscriber/) by [kmoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25724/kmoy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-01-25**:
There likely are other things you need to do... If you are in C++, you'll need to include new files, change templates and callback signatures, and recompile your workspace. It would be helpful to see your code, and if it is C++, your CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @jarvisschultz mentioned, you need to change the type also. A subscriber can only subscribe to messages of a specifc type. E. g. for C++ you need to bind your subcriber to a callback that can handle pointCloud2 msgs. An example for such callback including conversion to the native PCL type you need for accessing the data is given here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/136916/conversion-from-sensor_msgspointcloud2-to-pclpointcloudt/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0